# New column type tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I try to make a table with \newcolumntype. I am aware that the code as it is, is not working and not correctly used for the purpose I have.

My goal is to make a table with two colums (each column of the same size). => The table should look similar to the pic under the code but with the columns of the same width

Could you help me?

```
% page setup 
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 

% tables
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} 
\newcolumntype{P}[2]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}




\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\settowidth\colwidth{Ion-exchange chroma} % both boxes should have same with 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{\colwidth} }
   \toprule
   Native Gel & Denatured Gel  \\
   \midrule
\begin{itemize}
   \item   separation upon ---
       \end{itemize} & 
       \begin{itemize}
   \item   separation upon ---
       \end{itemize}        \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
   \end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image: I want to make it look like this but with every column of the same width]

Comment: I am very much aware of the mistake and the wrong using. I tried to make my request not contradictory. Unfortunately I am just a beginner.

Comment: Why are you definint `P` to take two arguments when you only use one (`#1`) additionally good idea to use `\RaggedRight\arraybackslash` otherwise ``\\`` might not work correctly

Comment: Where is `\colwidth` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs three adjustments in order to make it compile.

- The code requires a `\newlength\colwidth` declaration in the preamble.
- `\newcolumntype{P}[2]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}` has to be changed to

  ```
  \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
  ```
- Since there two columns in the `tabularx` environment,

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{\colwidth} }
  ```

  has to be changed to

  ```
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{2}{P{\colwidth}}}
  ```

Of course, "getting the code to compile" doesn't imply that your code does what you intend it to do. For instance, since the code doesn't contain any `X`-type columns, no useful purpose is served by employing a `tabularx` environment. I suggest you use a basic `tabular` environment instead. On the other hand, if you really do wish to employ a `tabularx` environment, you needn't set up the `P` column type; instead use the `X` column type.

---

The following screenshot is the result of applying the prececing suggestions. The upper table employs a `tabular` environment, the lower one uses a `tabularx` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 

% tables
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx} 

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} 
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\newlength\colwidth
\settowidth\colwidth{Ion-exchange chroma}  % measure intended width of 'P' columns

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering

\caption{Using a \texttt{tabular} env.\ and the \texttt{P} col.\ type\strut}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{2}{P{\colwidth}} @{} }
\toprule
   Native Gel & Denatured Gel  \\
   \midrule
   \begin{itemize}
     \item   separation upon ---
   \end{itemize} & 
   \begin{itemize}
     \item   separation upon ---
   \end{itemize}        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\hspace{1cm}

\caption{Using a \texttt{tabularx} env.\ and the \texttt{L} col. type\strut}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL @{} }
\toprule
   Native Gel & Denatured Gel  \\
   \midrule
   \begin{itemize}
     \item   separation upon ---
   \end{itemize} & 
   \begin{itemize}
     \item   separation upon ---
   \end{itemize}        \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your your adjustments to the code. It compiles but I get en error that the \colwidth has already be defined and I don't get two colums of the same size just one column and the text is overlaying

Comment: @ella - If I apply the three adjustments stated above to the code you provided in your posting, the code compiles. If they don't work for you, the only explanation is that your code is not the same as what you posted. I such a case, all bets are most certainly off.

Comment: I am sorry then than am not able to do it - never mind

Comment: @Elia - I've updated the answer to incorporate the additional information you provided in the revised query.

Answer (score 3):

1. make sure `\colwidth` is defined
2. Define P properly

   ```
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{%
      >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1} 
      >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}
     }
   ```

Then it seems to compile. Though your example does not make much sense as you are not using any `X` columnsm, so what is the point of using `tabularx` here?